# Сборка программы, использующей OpenSSL, для разных линуксов

Tags: c++, linux, qt, debian, openssl

Есть кроссплатформенная программа заказчика под Window/OsX/Linux - C++/Qt/Qml. С линуксами возникает проблема линковки Qt с openssl. Если компилирую программу на LinuxMint, то на Debian при запуске программа ругается на несовместимую версию openssl. На Ubuntu проблем не возникает. При этом, напрямую openssl в программе не используется. Если не ошибаюсь, только QNetworkAccessManager. То есть, openssl используется опосредственно через Qt либы.

Какие есть варианты решения этой проблемы? Есть ли возможность собирать один бинарник для Mint, Ubuntu и Debian?

По-умолчанию Qt динамически загружает openssl либы из системы. Но при сборке самой Qt используется конкретная либа openssl, которая может быть несовместима с openssl на целевой системе. Debian использует более свежие либы, чем Mint и Ubuntu. Как это разрулить - не понятно.

Comment: ну вообще говоря в системе может быть несколько версий библиотеки. Так что вам нужно просто доставить необходимую

Comment: Не понятно, как возникает такая проблема если QT использует либу, имеющуюся в системе. Один бинарик для нескольких дистрибутивов худо-бедно собрать можно, если все слинковать статически.

Comment: Andrio Skur, предположительно так? - положить openssl либу/либы "к себе" в каталог и указать LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Comment: VTT, если я правильно понимаю, статически линковать свои коды с Qt нельзя, так как программа хоть и предоставляется бесплатно, но исходники не открыты. Тут могу ошибаться, так как в лицензиях не силён )

Comment: @pier_nasos если нелинкованные `*.o` положить, то можно линковать статически

Comment: eri, статически с openssl? Если так, то мне не понятно, Qt автоматически из своих либ будет использовать статически прилинкованные, хотя сама Qt была собрана с другими либами openssl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если программа устанавливается в отдельную папку (как многие делают в /opt/) есть такой вариант.

## 1 LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Скопируй нужную версию `libcrypto` и `libssl` в папку с программой и сделай симлинки на libcrypto.so.1.1, libssl.so.1.1 и на libcrypto.so.1.0.0 .

Это поломает системный линковщик и все запустится хорошо.

Есть ещё моменты с `glibc`. Для запуска на старых дистрах понадобится сборка под `manylinux`.

## 2 LD_PRELOAD

Более аккуратный способ, который используют многие проприетарщики.

Также скидываем нужные библиотеки в папку с приложением и делаем обертку для запуска.

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_PRELOAD=./libcrypto.so ./my-programm
```

## 3 И если проект не большой, то линкуйте статический файл.

Comment: Старые линуксы не нужны (повезло). Статически линковаться с чем, с Qt или openssl?

Comment: полностью линкуй статически..) `-I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lQtGui -lQtCore -lpthread -lgthread-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0 -lpng -lz -lfreetype -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lSM -lICE -lXrender -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lXext -lX11 -lm -lQtCore -lpthread -lz -lm -ldl -lgthread-2.0 -pthread -lglib-2.0 -lrt
` например

Comment: в сдк вроде есть профили сборки

Comment: в первую очередь попробую LD_PRELOAD

Comment: только с glibc это не прокатывает. а она в последнее время сильно обновилась..

Comment: Сделал на LD_LIBRARY_PATH, работает. Проблемы с glibc не заметил пока.

Comment: заметишь на следующем LTS ;)
на текущих выпусках проблем не будет

Answer (score 1):

Сделать свой набор библиотек с которыми вы будете деплоить приложение. Это не единственные грабли на которые вы наступите пытаясь пользоватся системными библиотеками.